# Can i parse a binary XML file ( in res/xml ) with a SAX parser

Tags: android, xml, performance, binary, sax

To clarify my question :-)

I want to have the best of both worlds.

1. The speed of having a compressed xml
   file
2. The [speed of the SAX parser](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3824221_2/Android-XML-Parser-Performance.htm) (
   over a XmlResourceParser that is
   normally used with binary files )

Most important question is: Can this be done?

Closest i came to the solution is.

- **OR** open a raw resource ( not binary
  formatted )
- **OR** parse a binary xml file with a XmlResourceParser

I hope someone can help me get a bit further in this situation.

Edit: link to reflect SAX-parser speed

Comment: I have developed an APK extractor which is not dependent on AAPT. It includes parser which can parse any Android Binary XML content- http://code.google.com/p/apk-extractor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAX parser is **not** more efficient than XmlResourceParser for XML in raw resource.  Just use XmlResourceParser.

Comment: Can you give me a source that will back-up your statement ? Thanks

Comment: XmlPullParser in source you was not hitting pre-parsed XML in raw; it was hitting Xml from ordinary inputstream.  In that case SAX parser may be faster; but if you have option of putting file in res/raw, pull parser will be faster.

Comment: The XmlPullParser from a resource is 10-100x faster than any other parser last time I checked.  There is no need to even think about it.  A lot of the parsing work for you is done at build time by aapt; these are totally different than parsing a plain/real XML document on the device.

Comment: @ProgrammerXR -- BTW, if you didn't know hackbod is one of the key Android developers and about as authoritative as you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your xml file assets folder and you can use Sax parser

```
InputStream xmlFileStram = getAssets().open(filePath); // this gives the file in your asset folder
XmlHandler xmlHandler = new XmlHandler(activity);
SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(xmlFileStram, xmlHandler);
```

Comment: This will be a ton slower than using the XmlPullParser you get from putting the file in res/xml, so very not recommended.